# ERROR store.HBaseStore - [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@15a3cc7b

Tags: hbase

while using hbase with nutch I am getting following error
Mon Jun 23 23:46:24 PKT 2014, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable@7de8edf7, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed setting up proxy interface org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HRegionInterface to serverone/10.11.21.31:60020 after attempts=1

2014-06-23 23:46:24,208 ERROR store.HBaseStore - [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@15a3cc7b
2014-06-23 23:46:24,208 INFO  mapreduce.GoraRecordWriter - gora.buffer.write.limit = 10000
2014-06-23 23:46:24,212 INFO  crawl.SignatureFactory - Using Signature impl: org.apache.nutch.crawl.MD5Signature
2014-06-23 23:47:42,282 ERROR store.HBaseStore - Failed setting up proxy interface org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HRegionInterface to serverone/10.11.21.31:60020 after attempts=1
2014-06-23 23:47:42,282 ERROR store.HBaseStore - [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@6d05ab12

Comment: Have you found the answer of above bugg, if yes then please share it as I am also facing this problem

Answer (score 0):

One problem " ERROR store.HBaseStore - Failed setting up proxy interface " is because your hadoop daemons are not running. While the second " ERROR store.HBaseStore - [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElemen" is because of execption handling problem. So it will be solved when all daemons will work correctly.