# HBase Nutch error [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement

Tags: apache, hbase, web-crawler, nutch

My apache nutch is crawling and in log file following error is appeared.

ERROR store.HBaseStore - Connection refused 2014-11-17 00:00:38,255 ERROR store.HBaseStore - [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@6dce5061

How to remove this error. According to my search this error is because of hbase and not in nutch. This question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384793/error-store-hbasestore-ljava-lang-stacktraceelement15a3cc7b) but it has no answer.I have to bounty this question if do not get an answer that's why I am posting again.

Some informations of my small cluster is following ( 2 machine cluster)

On machine one, hadoop and hbase are running

On machine two, apache nutch crawler(2.2.1) is running.

When I check log files of hbase and hadoop, there isn't any information about bug. Because of this bug, crawled data in not going to be saved in hbase(machine1). That's a real problem for me and my crawler in not crawler properly. There is about 266 GB already crawled data in table.

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Tutorial?action=show&redirect=GORA_HBase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem "Connection refused" is simply because your region server is not running properly

Comment: Thanks as my regionserver was shutdown and I did not consider it